# How do I use app's each recycler view items links to go to particular item page on link click like flipkart shopping app

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to create a shopping app and I want if I share that particular app item link then customer should redirect to that particular item page. How do I implement it. I read about handling android app link but I couldn't get it properly. need some demo examples

Comment: Do you want to select from a list of items or from links?

Comment: Like I have a recycler view, and on item clicks I redirect user to that particular item description activity and in that activity I created a share button to share via whatsapp, messanger etc. And I want when other user clicks on that link he should redirect to that particular item. (Assuming that user already have this app)

Answer (score 0):

A possible logic I would use is the following, starting by saying that what you need as base is URI schema handling. You can find a good tutorial on the official Android dev website: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Once you implemented your URI schema provide to your app the ID of the items you are showing in your recyclerView. The activity that will handle your URI schema will receive the url with the ID of the shop item. At this point you can do whatever. You have the ID of the shop item and your app opened